# Using a rotation quaternion and a velocity to transform a point in a cartesian system

Tags: coordinate-systems, quaternions

The practical application of the following problem is a control system for aircraft.

I have done a lot of googling and searching this StackExchange looking for an answer but I haven't found anything that seems applicable here. On top of this the wikipedia articles on quaternions go over my head at times.

So, I have a unit quaternion which holds the current rotation of the aircraft and I plan to use a single velocity value and use these together as a velocity vector. The problem I have is that I do not know how to transform the location of the aircraft, which is held as a cartesian vector $(x, y, z)$, using the quaternion and velocity.

I would happily rework the concept if this is not the best way of going about velocity and transformations.

Comment: By "rotation", do you mean "orientation"?

Comment: Yeah, coloquially: which direction the aircraft is pointing.

Comment: Do you care at all about rotating the plane, or do you only care about the direction it's going?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I am fairly certain I understand how to apply rotations to the quaternion. I want to find out the new coordinates of the aircraft based on the velocity, the direction of the velocity. The distance covered is the $vt$ where $v$ is velocity and $t$ is time since the last transformation but how is this translated into the change in coordinates?

Comment: The answer depends on a lot... What is your body fixed coordinate system?  What is your global coordinate system?  Is your velocity represented in the body coordinate system?  Do you assume that the velocity is in line with the  primary axis of the vehicle?

Comment: I don't assume that the velocity is in line with the main axis of the vehicle, sorry if it wasn't clear but I only care about the direction of the velocity. What do you mean by body fixed and global coordinate systems?

Comment: Body fixed means that everything is relative to the plane and global coordinate systems means everything is relative to some fixed point.

Comment: You should post more information about your specific situation. How are you getting the orientation quaternion?

Comment: Through a gyroscope on an integrated circuit. The position of the vehicle is in the form of an integer vector where $(0, 0, 0)$ is the position where the vehicle lifted off.

Comment: I would just use a velocity vector for position, velocity, and acceleration. The only thing I would use quaternions for is orientation and rotation, and even then I would use vectors to represent torque and angular momentum.

Comment: Very well, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the direction something is pointing in from a unit quaternion in the form $\left<\cos\frac\theta2, d_x\sin\frac\theta2,d_y\sin\frac\theta2,d_z\sin\frac\theta2 \right>=\left<q_w,q_x,q_y,q_z\right>$ (first element is the real part, last three elements is the imaginary part) by taking $\sin\cos^{-1}q_w$ and dividing the last three parts by that result to get the direction vector, $\vec d$. From there, your change in position is $s\vec d\Delta t$, where $s$ is the speed.

A few things about quaternions: make sure that you normalize them every so often. The formula to rotate a point is $q*\vec v*q^{-1}=q*\vec v*(q*)$, where $*$ represents quaternion multiplication and $\vec v=\left<0,v_x,v_y,v_z\right>$. $q^{-1}=q*$ is only true for unit quaternions. $q*$ is just the conjugate of $q$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take some time to try to understand it before accepting it as an answer.

Comment: I'd suggest that you look up rotations in physics engines, as they need to do similar things with quaternions and the internet is chock full of stuff involving physics engines.

Comment: It is not true that $q^{-1}=-q$.  I believe that what you intended was $q^{-1}=q^*$ where $q^*$ is the conjugate (i.e. only the imaginary parts are negated).

Comment: @Tpofofn Right. Sorry about that.